# Progress bar for a function within a function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a function from a package that runs a series of other functions within it. I would love to show each of those functions as a separate Progressbar as they are run. Is this possible?

I have used `withProgress` but this only shows the 'outer' function and doesn't show me the progress of the functions that run within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO, next time try to provide a minimal [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm using the '[Progress indicator](http://shiny.rstudio-staging.com/articles/progress.html)' article provided by Rstudio as a base to answer you.

If I understood correctly, you are having trouble using `withProgress` with nested functions. You can use `withProgress` inside these functions:

```
library(shiny)

fun2 <- function(i,n,dat) {
  dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))
  incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  return(dat)
}

fun1 <- function(n) {
  dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))
  for (i in 1:n) { dat <- fun2(i,n,dat) }
  return(dat)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot # Re-run when button is clicked
    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      n <- 10
      dat <- fun1(n)
    })
    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(basicPage(
  plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),
  actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Another solution would be using global variables (just remember to be careful when using global variables).

```
library(shiny)
nprogress <- 10
iprogress <- 0

fun2 <- function(dat) {
  dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))
  incProgress(1/nprogress, detail = paste("Doing part", iprogress))
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  return(dat)
}

fun1 <- function(n) {
  dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))
  for (i in 1:n) {
    iprogress <<- i
    dat <- fun2(dat)
  }
  return(dat)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot # Re-run when button is clicked
    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      n <- 10
      nprogress <<- n
      dat <- fun1(n)
    })
    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(basicPage(
  plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),
  actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I had forgotten about `reactiveValues`. They may be a better solution than global variables.